# Is there a fully Standard compliant way to make the compiler paste the exact (binary) contents of a file in a source file?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I would like to provide the ease of use of Qt's Resource system (basically an xml containing a list of files, that is precompiled into a C++ source file containing a bunch of `char` arrays of the binary byte content of these files, which is compiled into the binary), in pure C++.

So I wonder, is the first and pretty much only requirement, even at all possible?

Can I compile a binary file into an object file?

I know it's not simply possible to #include another file in a C++11 raw string literal, but maybe there is a way around this. I would like to ditch the precompile step. Is there a way?

In the worst case, maybe a linker script and some voodoo in the code to access these bytes can make this functional, but I don't know if that's any better than the precompile step (which is certainly a lot more transparent...).

Comment: There's a proposal for [file literals](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0373r0.pdf).

Comment: `xxd -i some_file` generates a fully Standard compliant uchar array definition along with an unsigned int length variable.

Comment: This would be nice for embedding objects, such as binary fonts or images (as used in embedded systems).

Comment: 1) `objcopy` `binary blob` -> `object file`, 2) link object file conventionally in prog, 3) access blob by the default or defined symbols, is the stock solution for this. Is it news to you or do you just want the `objcopy`?

Answer (score 2):

> but I don't know if that's any better than the **precompile step** (which is certainly a lot more transparent...).

^^^^ That's the way to go (emphasis mine).

I don't see that there's something *standard compliant* to `#include` binary files directly into your code.

You'll need to have a tool that translates that binary file to something like

```
uint8_t myBinaryData = { 0x00, 0xfb, 0x42, /* ... */ }
```

and include that finally.

Simple python scripts or so will do fine.

Comment: I just mean that the translating tool can be written in C++ as well as in pyhton - after all, you can be sure that a C++ compiler is there.

Comment: An alternative is to use platform specific resource schemes where such exist. Windows has two main schemes, the Portable Executable resources and the .NET resource scheme built on top. In the old time a Mac executable had a resource "fork". Not sure how it's today, but surely there must be something to handle resources.